# Parsing Json to get the album ids for all 5 albums

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, spotify

Hey guys what would be the best way to extract the album ids from this json string, i converted it already to a JObject but am stuck, im fairly new to this so could use some assistance.
ex. the first album id i would want is "id" : "0v94MG5nbp4w6xdeFkfQrA" and there are 5 albums here so i want 5 albums

```
{
"albums" : {
"href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Farruko&type=album&market=US&offset=0&limit=5",
"items" : [ {
  "album_type" : "album",
  "artists" : [ {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "id" : "329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "name" : "Farruko",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
  } ],
  "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY", "VN" ],
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/0v94MG5nbp4w6xdeFkfQrA"
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/0v94MG5nbp4w6xdeFkfQrA",
  "id" : "0v94MG5nbp4w6xdeFkfQrA",
  "images" : [ {
    "height" : 640,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/61956518b48663e10775869d8dd4cffbe6f43ac8",
    "width" : 640
  }, {
    "height" : 300,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/6786555cdac766d6b42411f2a54d40b768470492",
    "width" : 300
  }, {
    "height" : 64,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/22d590419d90c411eba2d23561df223dc4e9907e",
    "width" : 64
  } ],
  "name" : "TrapXficante",
  "type" : "album",
  "uri" : "spotify:album:0v94MG5nbp4w6xdeFkfQrA"
}, {
  "album_type" : "album",
  "artists" : [ {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "id" : "329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "name" : "Farruko",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
  } ],
  "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY", "VN" ],
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/1zFp5Q3Dgo8wmKsmfZ23QX"
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/1zFp5Q3Dgo8wmKsmfZ23QX",
  "id" : "1zFp5Q3Dgo8wmKsmfZ23QX",
  "images" : [ {
    "height" : 640,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/617c7edb6b107e7dce12f42a9f3cc222046c0adc",
    "width" : 640
  }, {
    "height" : 300,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/a8b199f9a155388b4d4ab31ae96806649154ebdb",
    "width" : 300
  }, {
    "height" : 64,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/2f1d06be5e5ba87732962717e743fba730708d07",
    "width" : 64
  } ],
  "name" : "Visionary",
  "type" : "album",
  "uri" : "spotify:album:1zFp5Q3Dgo8wmKsmfZ23QX"
}, {
  "album_type" : "album",
  "artists" : [ {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "id" : "329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "name" : "Farruko",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
  } ],
  "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY", "VN" ],
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/3nXlHW1yqEnYKfi70zjeK4"
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/3nXlHW1yqEnYKfi70zjeK4",
  "id" : "3nXlHW1yqEnYKfi70zjeK4",
  "images" : [ {
    "height" : 640,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/874771d69c2b0df657bbd36998fc5deb75f920aa",
    "width" : 640
  }, {
    "height" : 300,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/b34224e47ebd44ea2c2ea92a38b3d203f2f96907",
    "width" : 300
  }, {
    "height" : 64,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/7a49b98bbe3d512d8d2ed204a823535e3fce817c",
    "width" : 64
  } ],
  "name" : "Farruko Presents Los Menores",
  "type" : "album",
  "uri" : "spotify:album:3nXlHW1yqEnYKfi70zjeK4"
}, {
  "album_type" : "single",
  "artists" : [ {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "id" : "329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO",
    "name" : "Farruko",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:329e4yvIujISKGKz1BZZbO"
  }, {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X",
    "id" : "4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X",
    "name" : "Bad Bunny",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:4q3ewBCX7sLwd24euuV69X"
  }, {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/1i8SpTcr7yvPOmcqrbnVXY"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1i8SpTcr7yvPOmcqrbnVXY",
    "id" : "1i8SpTcr7yvPOmcqrbnVXY",
    "name" : "Ozuna",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:1i8SpTcr7yvPOmcqrbnVXY"
  } ],
  "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY", "VN" ],
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/5wtK6rD6OVbGxxiQ7gzgfD"
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/5wtK6rD6OVbGxxiQ7gzgfD",
  "id" : "5wtK6rD6OVbGxxiQ7gzgfD",
  "images" : [ {
    "height" : 600,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c011680190a6e2273de0ede0e19fd1e2b4f60cd7",
    "width" : 600
  }, {
    "height" : 300,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/4c1557e949155fe75563ac14862e45388722ffa3",
    "width" : 300
  }, {
    "height" : 64,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/b0bfe473cdc9c2c1de7c7204986797be0592c8ea",
    "width" : 64
  } ],
  "name" : "Diles",
  "type" : "album",
  "uri" : "spotify:album:5wtK6rD6OVbGxxiQ7gzgfD"
}, {
  "album_type" : "single",
  "artists" : [ {
    "external_urls" : {
      "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2R21vXR83lH98kGeO99Y66"
    },
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/2R21vXR83lH98kGeO99Y66",
    "id" : "2R21vXR83lH98kGeO99Y66",
    "name" : "Anuel Aa",
    "type" : "artist",
    "uri" : "spotify:artist:2R21vXR83lH98kGeO99Y66"
  } ],
  "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TH", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY", "VN" ],
  "external_urls" : {
    "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/album/2ucmNNr2Y9ZI7fP4oAMdIj"
  },
  "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/2ucmNNr2Y9ZI7fP4oAMdIj",
  "id" : "2ucmNNr2Y9ZI7fP4oAMdIj",
  "images" : [ {
    "height" : 640,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/03053a17a55677759afe8ffa9745f4da3b9228d6",
    "width" : 640
  }, {
    "height" : 300,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/c4c377376efe405009fedbc2deb829b5a7d348b7",
    "width" : 300
  }, {
    "height" : 64,
    "url" : "https://i.scdn.co/image/f55f20474ebebabf8816a5474ce9896978773c39",
    "width" : 64
  } ],
  "name" : "Sola (Remix) [feat. Daddy Yankee, Wisin, Farruko, Zion & Lennox]",
  "type" : "album",
  "uri" : "spotify:album:2ucmNNr2Y9ZI7fP4oAMdIj"
} ],
"limit" : 5,
"next" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=Farruko&type=album&market=US&offset=5&limit=5",
"offset" : 0,
"previous" : null,
"total" : 150
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deserialize to a concrete class.. [See how those class are generated](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
var rootObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SOTest.RootObject>(json);
foreach(var item in rootObj.albums.items)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.id);
}
```

---

```
public class SOTest
{
    public class ExternalUrls
    {
        public string spotify { get; set; }
    }

    public class Artist
    {
        public ExternalUrls external_urls { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }


    public class Image
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string album_type { get; set; }
        public List<Artist> artists { get; set; }
        public List<string> available_markets { get; set; }
        public ExternalUrls external_urls { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Image> images { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }

    public class Albums
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
        public object previous { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Albums albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks your answered helped me understand what was going on